# Simple Java Callback is not working

Tags: java, interface, callback

```
interface CallableInterface
{
    void callBackMethod();
}

class Worker
{   
    public static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    static Timer t = new Timer();

    public void addToList(String newAdd, CallableInterface callback)
    {   
        names.add("BMW");
        names.add("DODGE");

        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {     
                names.add(newAdd);
            }
        }, 5000);

       callback.callBackMethod();
    }

    public void printList(){
        System.out.println(Worker.names);
    }
}


class Boss implements CallableInterface
{   
    Worker w1 = new Worker();

    public Boss(String carName)
    {   
        w1.addToList(carName, this);
    }
    public void callBackMethod()
    {
        w1.printList();
    }
}


public class IntroCallbacks
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Boss b = new Boss("Mercedes");   
    }
}
```

I am simulating a network delay using a timer. The idea is to wait for the timer to finish (in this case 5 seconds) and then to print the arrayList. No matter what i do to the code i always get [BMW, DODGE] only.

It should be [BMW, DODGE, MERCEDES].

What am i missing?

Comment: You are calling the callback method then, 5s later, adding MERCEDES. You may want to call the callback inside the `run()` method.

Comment: Note: you can just use `Runnable` rather than defining your own `CallbackInterface`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Worker::addToList` calls `Boss::callBackMethod` immediately after scheduling the timer. This prints the list, which only currently has 2 elements. ~4.99 seconds later, the final element is added to the list but it's already been printed.

If you only want to print the list after the 3rd element is added, move the invocation of the callback to after that element is added:

```
public void addToList(String newAdd, CallableInterface callback)
{   
    names.add("BMW");
    names.add("DODGE");

    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {     
            names.add(newAdd);
            callback.callBackMethod();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

or use some synchronization mechanism like a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Comment: Thanks Michael :)

Comment: This works but putting the call to the callback in there feels a little dirty to me. It feels like a cross-cutting concern, and I think a cleaner way might be with chaining promises, or in Java, `CompletableFuture`s.

Comment: @DavidConrad Agree but play to your audience. Look at his code and seriously ask yourself whether he's likely to understand a word of what you just said. I did suggest using synchronisation aids at the bottom in case he wanted to look into it.

Comment: Well, that's why I just posted a separated answer demonstrating it. Not saying your answer isn't good.

Comment: @Michael you are right. I was confused by DavidConrad's answer because i am a beginner in Java. But, with simple google search i became familiar with CountDownLatch and CompletableFuture and i am currently in the process of using them to professionalize my code ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `CompletableFuture` to chain the printing after the addition of the name. You can use a delayed `Executor` instead of a `Timer` to introduce the 5 second delay.

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

class Worker {
    private List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    public CompletableFuture<Void> addToList(String name, Runnable callback) {
        names.add("BMW");
        names.add("DODGE");

        Executor in5seconds = CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(5, SECONDS);

        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> names.add(name), in5seconds)
            .thenRun(callback::run);
    }

    public void printList() {
        System.out.println(names);
    }
}

class Boss implements Runnable {
    private Worker worker = new Worker();
    private CompletableFuture<Void> future;

    public Boss(String carName) {
        future = worker.addToList(carName, this);
    }

    public void run() {
        worker.printList();
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Void> getFuture() {
        return future;
    }
}

public class IntroCallbacks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boss boss = new Boss("Mercedes");
        boss.getFuture().join();
    }
}
```

It is necessary to wait until the future `isDone()` or to `join()` at the end, otherwise the program would end and the background daemon thread would be terminated before any of the interesting stuff (including the output) happened.

Comment: Nice. Worth noting `CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor` is only present in Java 9 and up because a lot of people haven't made the switch yet.

Comment: @Michael Oh, good call. I just looked in the docs and found it there. Didn't notice it was only since Java 9.

Comment: Thank you @DavidConrad. The Code looks cleaner hehe. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

This code will fix your issue.. :)

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    interface CallableInterface
    {
        void callBackMethod();
    }

    class Worker
    {   
        public static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        static Timer t = new Timer();

        public void addToList(String newAdd, CallableInterface callback)
        {   
            names.add("BMW");
            names.add("DODGE");

            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {     
                    names.add(newAdd);
                    callback.callBackMethod();
                }
            }, 5000);


        }

        public void printList(){
            System.out.println(Worker.names);
        }
    }


    class Boss implements CallableInterface
    {   
        Worker w1 = new Worker();

        public Boss(String carName)
        {   
            w1.addToList(carName, this);
        }
        public void callBackMethod()
        {
            w1.printList();
        }
    }

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Boss b = new Boss("Mercedes");   

        }

    }
```

Comment: And why will it?